# Is there a way to use the code for OutOfOrder, to make InOrder as simple as OutOfOrder?

Tags: java, if-statement, return, boolean, call

I have having a hard time trialling methods using ONLY the rules of logic and using the OutOfOrder code, to make InOrder as simple as OurOfOrder.

```
public class InOrder {
//Don't change this
public boolean OutOfOrder(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
return (n1 > n2) || (n2 > n3);
}

//The original and messy InOrder, leave this as an example of what not to do
public boolean inOrder(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
if (n2 > n1) {
  if (n3 > n2) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} else if (n2 == n1) {
  if (n3 == n1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} else {
  return false;
}
}

//The new and improved InOrder for part 5, call OutOfOrder
public boolean inOrder5a(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
return true; //replace this
}

//The newer and improved InOrder for part 6, inline
public boolean inOrder5b(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
return true;//replace this
}

}
```

Comment: You mean `return (n1 <= n2 && n2 <= n3);` ? You haven't actually told us what these methods are supposed to do.

Comment: `return !OutOfOrder(n1, n2, n3);` - assuming that if it's not "out of order" it must be "in order" :/

Comment: Note that a construct like `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` can be replaced by just `return condition;`, already simplifying your logic extremely.

Comment: Note that your current code is not correct. It behaves wrong for the situation `n1 < n2` with `n2 == n3`. So for example `n1 = 4`, `n2 = 6`, `n3 = 6`. Your code is saying `false` although it is in order.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that numbers are either in order or out of order, there is no third option.

So you can implement `inOrder` as:

```
public boolean inOrder(int n1, int n2, int n3) {
    return !outOfOrder(n1, n2, n3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have said: `(n2 >= n1 && n3 >= n2)`